# Clear setuid permission using numeric mode

Tags: permissions, chmod, setuid

On an Ubuntu Linux I have a directory with the setuid bit set (`drwsr-xr-x`) which I want to unset.

Neither `chmod 755` nor `chmod 0755` nor `chmod 00755` (I though maybe the first 0 is interpreted as just "this is octal") cleared the setuid bit. However, `chmod u-s` did.

What is the correct numeric mode to clear the setuid bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly. this seems to be impossible using GNU `chmod`, and that's a feature.  From the `info` entry on `chmod` on my system; note how, whilst the entry on setting the bits makes reference to symbolic and numeric modes, the entry on clearing them refers only to symbolic (`ug-s`) mode:

> 27.4 Directories and the Set-User-ID and Set-Group-ID Bits
>
> These convenience mechanisms rely on the set-user-ID and
>   set-group-ID bits of directories.  If commands like `chmod' and`
>   mkdir' routinely cleared these bits on directories, the mechanisms
>   would be less convenient and it would be harder to share files. 
>   Therefore, a command like `chmod' does not affect the set-user-ID or
>   set-group-ID bits of a directory unless the user specifically mentions
>   them in a symbolic mode, or sets them in a numeric mode.
>
> [...]
>
> If
>   you want to try to set these bits, you must mention them explicitly in
>   the symbolic or numeric modes, e.g.:
>
> [...]
>
> If you want to try to
>   clear these bits, you must mention them explicitly in a symbolic mode,
>   e.g.:
>
> [...]
>
> This behavior is a GNU extension.  Portable scripts
>   should not rely on requests to set or clear these bits on directories,
>   as POSIX allows implementations to ignore these requests.